# Como puedo cargar una api en una página diferente a mainpage?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, net, maui

no me carga la API fuera del MainPage, he copiado el código y al dar al botón me falla, el mainpage abre otr apagina que hace de menu y al acceder a la definitiva falla al cargar la lista, no parece que entre ni al método

Este es el código que pongo en newpage1:

```
namespace MauiApp1.Pagina;
using MauiApp1.Servicios;

    public partial class NewPage1 : ContentPage
    {
        private readonly IRickAndMortyServices _rickAndMortyServices;
        public NewPage1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
    
        }

    private async void OnCounterClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        loading.IsVisible = true;
        var data = await _rickAndMortyServices.Obtener();
        listViewPersonajes.ItemsSource = data;
        loading.IsVisible = false;
    }
}
```

y este es el error:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an
> instance of an object.'

La llamada es esta:

```
private void OnImage1Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Navigation.PushAsync(new Pagina.NewPage1());
}
```

Por si acaso dejo el servicio:

```
using MauiApp1.Modelo;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Nodes;

namespace MauiApp1.Servicios
{
    public class RickANDmortyServices : IRickAndMortyServices
    {
        private string urlApi = "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character";
        public async Task<List<Personajes>> Obtener()
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();
            var response = await client.GetAsync(urlApi);
            var responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            JsonNode nodos = JsonNode.Parse(responseBody);
            JsonNode results = nodos["results"];

            var personajesData = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Personajes>>(results.ToString());
            return personajesData;
        }
    }
}
```

Alguna idea de que puede pasar? llevo horas buscando y no encuentro nada